# changing size of addthis social sharing buttons

Tags: addthis

Using the 'AddThis' smart API for social sharing, does anyone know how to set the buttons to small size? Seems like it should be a simple setting but I've been unable to find it and am stuck with the 32 x 32. 
http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1200473-smart-layers-api#.Usw3JmRDs9E

So far I have the following code and tried adding width and height but it didn't work:

```
addthis.layers({
    'theme' : 'transparent',
    'share' : {
    'position' : 'left',
    'services' : 'facebook, twitter, linkedin, email, print, more',
    //'width' :  "16px",
    //'height' :  "16px"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone wonders, turns out the smart API doesn't allow size changes on the buttons. Only the share button option allows size changes: https://www.addthis.com/get/sharing

Answer (score 0):

My solution for changing size of addthis social sharing sidebar / buttons is to add a javascript snippet, as follows, at the botttom, after the addthis script:

```
function shrink() {
  var rslt = $('.atss a .at-icon-wrapper').css ( { padding: 0, width: '32px' } );
  //console.log (rslt.length, rslt);  // uncomment this if you want to debug
  if (rslt.length == 0)
    setTimeout (shrink, 500);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setTimeout (shrink, 500);
});
```

This works, and can be seen in action at https://eracks.com - and the resize is never visible (at least I have never seen it yet), no matter what the connection speed / bandwidth is.

j